# Third party components in react-final-form with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

Ive got a components which requires some properties

```
import { Input, ComponentProps } from 'ThirdPartyLib';

import * as React from 'react';
import { FieldRenderProps } from 'react-final-form';

type Props = FieldRenderProps<string, HTMLElement> & ComponentProps;

export const TextInput: React.FC<Props> = ({
    input,
    meta: { touched, error },
    ...rest
}: Props) => (
    <Input invalid={touched && error} errorText={error} {...input} {...rest} />
);
```

**ComponentProps** is a interface that have some mandatory props e.x. id.
When I try to use **TextInput** component:

```
<TextInput />
```

It doesn't compile because I didn't pass required props. But when I do:

```
<Field
    name={'email'}
    component={TextInput}
/>
```

It compiles without problem.

Is it a way to force **Field** to also look for **ComponentProps**?

Comment: So, why don't you pass the required props to `TextInput`? if the props are optional, why not defining them as optional in type declaration?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi that is desirable that **TextInput** doesn't compile, I just want to achieve the same result using **Field** component - I want it to do not compile when required component props are not passed

Comment: Ah, ok it was not clear to me what you want to achieve.  can you please send the type declaration of  `component` prop in `Field` component?  it might be `component?: React.ReactNode;`

Comment: Anyway, I think [this example](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/field-level-validation) will hep you